# How to fill a "Relevant Knowledge/Training Skills" section in an application form for a Master Degree

Tags: application

I am applying for a Master in Law (distance learning) in a top-ranked UK university.
To do that, I need to fill in a form with several details and then upload some specific documents. One of the questions of the form is "Relevant Knowledge/Skills" with a word cap of 500 words.

In my past applications (jobs/academia), aside from my Personal Statement, I usually have sent a copy of my CV. Filling out a box with 500 words about my knowledge and/or skills is a new thing for me.

What do you recommend to handle this requirement successfully? What approach should I use for drafting an appealing section for my application? (e.g., not only put a bullet list with specific knowledge or technical skills)

Comment: Do you have an undergraduate degree?

Comment: Yes. A LL.B in my country

Comment: Some universities supply information about how to complete applications to their courses on their application website. Perhaps there is some useful information there.

Comment: What major in your Masters in Law? Maybe write 500 words on the specific area of law that you want to specialise in, why, what you hope to learn etc.